# Java library inspector?

Tags: java

I am currently working on a mantenance project that is written in Java. We are currently working to clean up the code some and try to provide a little more organization to the project overall.

The list of libraries that are included in the build have grown long, and honestly no one remains that knows/remembers what each library is used for or why? So I am looking for a tool that would be able to essentially find where the library is used in the code. Essentially like a find usage function in an IDE has for functions.

Does such a tool exist? I am curently using Netbeans and as mentioned our code is in java.

I know I could remove each library and compile the project for each library to find the usages, but it just seems there should be a better way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you're using NetBeans, I suggest the [SQE](https://sqe.dev.java.net/) plugin, which includes [Dependency Finder](http://depfind.sourceforge.net/). (And if you weren't already using FindBugs, this is a good time to start.)

Answer (score 1):

Try using [jarjar](http://code.google.com/p/jarjar/).  It has a command line interface that will analyze your dependency tree.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't used it for a few years but I remember that [JDepend](http://www.clarkware.com/software/JDepend.html) was useful when I was in a similar situation.

Answer (score 0):

You could let Eclipse remove unnecessary imports for you. Then simply search through the code for imports relating to a specific library's package name.

Comment: That was what I was trying to avoid having to do though. I was kinda looking for something a little quicker.